# Using convert command as php never re-sizes the images

Tags: php

Im using the following function:

```
function resizeTo($source, $dest) {
    system("convert $source -resize 100x100 $dest 2>&1");
}
```

However it never re-sizes the images. I've uploaded images 1920 wide and it doesn't do anything to re-size it.

If i run the command in shell it works fine though re-sizes the image perfectly.

I'm not getting any errors when running the script and the image uploads fine.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: What is the return value of `system` function?

Comment: Nothing is being output.

Comment: still nothing being output. Image uploads fine just its the original file size

Comment: Do you have error reporting on? Is system() enabled on your environment?

Comment: Error reporting is on and i'm not sure about system, How can i check?

Comment: Could you show us the code you are using to call the function?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the PHP [ImageMagick](http://php.net/imagick) extension, in Python you can use [wand](http://wand-py.org)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php

It is faster (sometimes) and not need to call the program via 'system'